# How do I Deserialize Json multiple results?

Tags: c#

I have string like below (2 lines are in one string variable), How do I divide into 2 strings and deserialize using JsonConvert class in C#

```
 {"operation":"waiting","wait":12121212}
 {"operation":"result","firstname":"bill", "lastname":"last"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the string into an array of strings using the new line separator and then JSON deserialize each line. To split a string you could use the [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method.

For example:

```
string input = "... your input string ...";
string[] lines = input.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    // you could use a JSON serializer here to deserialize the line
    // and possibly add it to some result collection
}
```